# A valid POST param value is empty in cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

When posting data through my form, some of the fields become empty, either `None` or `''` in `cleaned_data`. They are passed correctly and still there in `request.POST`. For example:

**forms.py**

```
class NotificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    WEEKDAY_OPTIONS = no_chosen_day + [
        (i, v)
        for i, v in enumerate(calendar.day_name)
    ]
    schedule_weekday = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=WEEKDAY_OPTIONS,
        label="Day of the week",
        disabled=True,
        required=False,
    )

    def clean_schedule_weekday(self):
        __import__('pprint').pprint(self.cleaned_data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    notification_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    schedule_weekday = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

No other clean methods in `forms.py`.
The field value is already empty in the `clean_schedule_weekday` method:

```
{'schedule_weekday': '',}
```

While printing out `request.POST` in `views.py` still gives:

```
{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'schedule_weekday': '0'}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the reason is I set `disabled=True` where I define the field in the class vars. Instead, it must be set in `___init__()`:

```
self.fields['schedule_weekday'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```